# Phonegap No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: wordpress, cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I am creating a basic phonegap app which is powered by a wordpress site.

Everytime i process the below with correct details i get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com?action=login&username=user&password=password. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Here is my code:

```
function fetch_and_display_posts()
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "myurlhere");
    xhr.onload = function(){
        var posts_array = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        var html = "";

        for(var count = 0; count < posts_array.length; count++)
        {
            var title = posts_array[count][0];
            var link = posts_array[count][1];
            var date = posts_array[count][2];
            var image = posts_array[count][3];

            html = html + "<li>" + "<a href='javascript:open_browser(\"" + link + "\")'>" + "<img height='128' width='128' src='" + image + "'>" + "<h2>" + title + "</h2>" + "<p>" + date + "</p></a></li>";
        }

        document.getElementById("posts").innerHTML = html;
        $("#posts").listview("refresh");
    }
    xhr.send();
}

function login()
{
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    if(username == "")
    {
        navigator.notification.alert("Please enter username", null, "Username Missing", "OK");
        return;
    }

    if(password == "")
    {
        navigator.notification.alert("Please enter password", null, "Password Missing", "OK");  
        return;
    }

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "http://example.com?action=login&username=" + encodeURIComponent(username) + "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(password));
    xhr.onload = function(){
        if(xhr.responseText == "FALSE")
        {
            navigator.notification.alert("Wrong Username and Password", null, "Wrong Creds", "Try Again");
        }
        else if(xhr.responseText == "TRUE")
        {

            fetch_and_display_posts();
            $("#page_two_link").click();
        }
    }   
    xhr.send();
}

function open_browser(link)
{
    window.open(link, '_blank', 'location=yes');
}
```

How can i resolve this issue? I believe its to do with cross domain security?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have CORS issue.

Open your Server side code and the following   to top of your script.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```